# Why use sql language instead of mdx language in ssrs?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

I was looking at pluralsight´s SSRS-training and they used regular sql to get data to the datasets. I am just learning mdx and when I work with datasets I so far only use mdx to get data. Should/could I mix this, should I use SQL instead of mdx? I don´t want to, now that I started to enjoy mdx..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MDX is often used against multidimensional cubes and have some commands specifically for this purpose which SQL does not have. If your datasource is a database, and not a cube however SQL is most commonly used as far as I know.

Comparison of SQL and MDX: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216779%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: The MSDN link makes it sound like MDX is a superset of SQL, but I think that is very misleading.  MDX is a used for some very specific purposes, and it is not used outside those purposes.  SQL is the general standard we use for almost everything that involves databases, and it translates nearly unchanged to MySQL, Oracle, and every accounting package out there.  In general, you will need SQL and you should learn it now.  In particular, SSRS reporting should be based on SQL and not MDX.  You do yourself no favors if you skip SQL.

Comment: I think I should use MDX when query against cube, guess they (pluralsight) used a relational db, didn´t thought about that...

Answer (score 3):

MDX language = OLAP Cubes (SSAS)

SQL language = Relational databases.

OLAP cubes are used for reporting and performance reasons. When data or information is needed and it involves large aggregations of data or calculations of large amounts of data from a relational database, a OALP cube can be created to sometimes better handle the demands of the data requirements. MDX is the query language used to pull data from the cube.

Here's an example to help. You need to pull some data for a report. You could use a SQL statement or a cube (MDX) for this data. You test using a SQL statement, but the query takes 5 minutes to run. Or with a cube, you could add the equivalent of the SQL statement into the cube design where it will make the equivalent of the SQL query results available instantly. How is this possible? Cube's are relational databases full of pre-run calculations and aggregations of data. Pre-run, meaning they were run or processed at some earlier time, likely at night when everyone was home.

MDX is specific to only one reporting program, SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). SQL is tied to multiple different database programs. Usually people who know MDX are already an expert or very familiar with SQL. I'd learn SQL first since there are many more applications for it than MDX>